# route table with eth0 and ppp0 broken

Tags: route, ppp, pptp, pppd

I used [this guide](http://www.adminsehow.com/2010/04/connect-to-pptp-vpn-from-linux-only-by-one-command/) to connect to my VPN server (pptp) which is the only one guide that worked from many tutorials.

After connecting to the VPN server the route table looks like below and sometimes it's only the last 2 lines (very random I'm sure there's a reason).

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

**My set up:** (IPs changed in example to make it simple)

- Local computer (centos) running on 192.168.1.20
- This connects to external VPN (ubuntu) on 35.100.100.35 (internet) with internal VPN local IP 192.168.0.1
- When centos is connected, interface ppp0 gets added with the IP 192.168.0.2

However, I need all traffic from 192.168.0.2 to be routed via 192.168.0.1 (vpn server). Currently it uses local internet.

I've tried so many variations and cannot get it right.

`route add default ppp0` used to work but with the route tables destroyed it's not working anymore.

**What should the route table look like?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Issue

I would recommend a separate routing table for this, since I assume the traffic arriving at `192.168.0.2` has a source address of `35.100.100.35`. The issue you're having is that `35.100.100.35` isn't listed in your routing table, so the default is being used.

You might be able to get away with something as simple as:

```
ip route add 35.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.0.1 dev ppp0
```

So that when your machine tries to respond to a `35` address, it does so on the `ppp0` interface.

The more robust/elaborate version follows.

NOTE: You should reboot your machine to clear out any temporary changes you've made to your routing table.

---

### Routing Rules

A simple enough routing rule is to have any traffic that is destined to or from a specific IP or subnet to use a different routing table:

```
ip rule add from [interface ip]/[netmask] tab [table number] priority [priority]
ip rule add to [interface ip]/[netmask] tab [table number] priority [priority]
```

In this case you're concerned about traffic arriving at `192.168.0.2` (your `ppp0` device IP). You'll need to create a new routing table by adding to the file: `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. The syntax is `[table number]    [table name]`. I normally use the interface name as the table name, keep things simple.

```
echo "168   ppp0" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 

ip rule add from 192.168.0.2/32 tab 168 priority 101
ip rule add to 192.168.0.2/32 tab 168 priority 101
```

This should cause all traffic addressed to `192.168.0.2` to match routing table `168`, as well as any traffic that is in response to traffic in that table.

---

### Using New Routing Tables

Now we've directed traffic to that routing table `168`, but it would be empty, only need to add a default route to it now.

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev ppp0 table 168
```

This adds a default route to table `168`, which is simply to say use interface `ppp0`.

---

### What It Looks Like

Your routing tables in the end should probably look like this:

```
# ip route show
default dev eth0 proto static metric 1024
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.20
192.168.0.0/24 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.2
```

This is your standard routing table, the table normally used for traffic. As for the routes here: the default as you've probably originally defined, and the second two are inferred based on the IP address of your interfaces.

```
# ip rule show
0:       from all lookup local
101:     from 192.168.0.2 lookup ppp0
101:     from all to 192.168.0.2 lookup ppp0
```

This lists your routing rules, format is "[priority]:  [rule] lookup [table]". This example states that normally, use the local routing table. If the traffic is to or from 192.168.0.2 use the routing table named `ppp0`.

```
# ip route show table ppp0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev ppp0
```

This shows the routing table named `ppp0`, which should just send all traffic out `ppp0`.

---

### End Result

The end result of this is that when traffic is heading to or from the IP of your `ppp0` interface, it will use the routing table called `ppp0`. The routing table `ppp0` just send all traffic out device `ppp0`.

Comment: Thanks. Machine rebooted. PPTP connected again but this line is the only one that comes up for ppp0 `35.100.100.35   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0` - When I get IP, it's still showing the local ISP public IP from the linux machine instead of the VPN public IP

Comment: @Onimusha did you set up the rule and all?

Comment: Yes I did. When going the above it doesn't really trigger or set up anything. I've noticed that every linux works differently and there's so many guides to do it differently. Trial and error just seems to break the system. I will mark you answer as accepted because it was detailed enough to add a simple route `0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.0.1 dev ppp0 ` for it to use the ppp0 connection for all traffic. The rest is just too complicated.

Comment: @Onimusha you may find using `tcpdump` may be useful, to see what traffic is actually coming into your machine, then you can tailor rules/routes to that traffic specifically.

Comment: Thanks Centimane, that's definitely something I was trying to figure how to do. Nice one

Answer (score 0):

`route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.0.1 dev ppp0`

Comment: One line answered are not preferred, please add some sort of explanation as to how this answers the question.

Comment: This might be a routing statement as (indirectly) asked, but I'm not sure it precisely answers the question of routing just 192.168.0.2 -- it routes the entire subnet.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't help, doesn't answer anything I asked nor does it help in any way